# Visual Studio 2005 - Watch Unable to evaluate expression

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I am trying to debug my program but when I need to evaluate an expression, the quick watch box won't let me, instead this error appears: "Unable to evaluate expression" with EVERYTHING I want to watch. 
It doesn't even show me a local variable!!

Thaks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I recently installed VS 2010 and that installation somehow broke my VS 2005. I had to uninstall VS 2010 in order to resolve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to check what your project settings are and which configuration you are running.

This mostly happens when you try to run debug while having Release (or another configuration without debug information) selected.

The reason this is a problem is that configurations without debug information still allow you to run in "debug" mode. This means you're able to set breakpoints, but does not allow you to watch and edit variable values the way you can in normal debug configurations.

Comment: Every project has multiple available configurations. When you compile, the currently chosen configuration will be used. See it as different profiles for building the same project.

By default, two configurations exist for each project: One called Debug and one called Release.

Debug has debug information embedded, while Release does not. Mostly, the error you describe comes from trying to debug code by starting "Debug" while having Release chosen. This will work with breakpoints, but won't allow you to check values of your variables.

Comment: yes yes, but it's not on Release.. I have "debug" chosen on the combo above all.